# Stop App Store prompting for specific system update

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I have a Brother MFC printer, and installed the latest drivers from the Brother website. All is good, everything works.

The App Store now prompts me that there is an update available: Brother Printer Software Update 2.10. This looks like an Apple package, and isn't the same as the Brother one.

With this installed I can't print, and it doesn't even think the printer has a scanner attached. After deleting the printer, re-installing the Brother package, and re-adding the printer it's all working again.

It appears in the top Software Update section of the Updates page, not in the section below for regular app updates.

Is there a way to specifically block this one update? I know app updates have been discussed in other questions, this isn't it.

I'm on 10.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if you click on "More Info" and expand the update fully, you can then right-click on it and choose "Ignore Update".

Comment: What ALEX said is correct. (and it's supposed to work that way). BUT...
Turns out that the right-click option only works in certain cases. No documentation or explanation as to why. Just hundreds of threads on various forums complaining that this doesn't consistently work.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS X 10.8.3:

Right clicking option for me says "Hide update". That would solve the OP's problem of blocking the one update.

However, it would be nice to have some Preferences to customize.